# How to access "parent" index of map() function inside "child" map()

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of array of dates. I need to make a calendar-like table of those dates. Each cell is a stateless component with two buttons, each button going to have a callback function modifying data corresponding to given date.

Table is made by mapping the "parent" array consisting arrays of days (each "child array has length >= 6 for sake of being a calendar) and then each child array is mapped, thus creating rows.

But since each table row is made by mapping separate array, how do I keep track of number of cells in general? I want to each cell have unique index despite being made by separate map().

Why do I want that? Because clicking on a button inside each cell needs to modify some data corresponding to date the cell represents

I have tried mapping array of dates (which is used to make array of arrays) to object to have easy access to each date through callback methods.

I tried some arithmetic operations on "parent" and "child" map() methods but I guess index prop isn't inherited

I even tried to create an array with dates as custom keys, each element being an array of two elements (that's the data I need to operate on through those callbacks)

Example array of array of dates

```
let arrayOfWeeks = [
 [
  "01.05.2019",
  "02.05.2019",
  "03.05.2019",
  "04.05.2019",
  "05.05.2019",
  "06.05.2019",
  "07.05.2019",
 ],
 [
  "08.05.2019",
  "09.05.2019",
  "10.05.2019",
  "11.05.2019",
  "12.05.2019",
  "13.05.2019",
  "14.05.2019",
  ]
]
```

Calendar table

```
<tbody>
  {arrayOfWeeks.map((row, index) =>
    <tr key={index}>
      {row.map((date, index) =>
        <CalendarCell key={index} date={date} index={index} callback={() => this.onCallback(someProps)} />
      )}
    </tr>
  )}
</tbody>
```

CalendarCell stateless component

```
const CalendarCell = (props: any) => (
    <td>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                {props.date}
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <Button onClick={props.onCallback}>1</Button>
                <Button onClick={props.onCallback}>2</Button>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </td>
)
```

I want each `CalendarCell` component to have unique key/index/id/whatever to be able to access an array in parent component through them

---

**UPDATE:**
Thanks Mishel!

Here is what fixed code looks like

```
<tbody>
  {arrayOfWeeks.map((row, index) =>
    <tr key={index}>
      {row.map((date, index2) =>
        <CallendarCell key={index} date={date} index={index * 7 + index2} onCallback={this.onCallback} />
     )}
   </tr>
  )}
</tbody>
```

Since there are two unique names for indexes, some maths can be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use different names for index. something like:

```
<tbody>
    {arrayOfWeeks.map((row, index) =>
        <tr key={index}>
            {row.map((date, index2) =>
                <CalendarCell key={index} date={date} index={index}
                 callback={() => this.onCallback(someProps)} />
            )}
               </tr>
    )}
</tbody>
```

in general:

when you have two functions nested in each other like that you can do this:

```
const A = (a)=>{
  const b = (b)=>{
    console.log('A:',a)
    console.log('B:',b)
  }
  b(2);
}
a('1');
//output will be:
// A:1
// B:2
```

If this is not clear for you or you have questions let me know